# Is it possible to check which "children" DIV was clicked

Tags: jquery, event-handling

If I write the listener as below,

```
$('.parent').bind('click', function() {
//...
})

<div class="parent">
    <div class="children1"></div>
    <div class="children2"></div>
    <div class="children3"></div>
</div>
```

For example I clicked `children2`, Is it possible to check which "children" DIV under `parent` was clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can look at `e.target` (change your handler to accept `e` as an argument), possibly using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to get the first `div` ancestor of the actual element clicked (in case those child `div`s have descendants).

```
$('.parent').bind('click', function(e) {
    // Here, `e.target` is the DOM element where the click occurred
    var div = $(e.target).closest('div');
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/acoqax/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/acoqax/1/edit)

Alternately, if you *only* want the handler to fire when one of the children is clicked, you can use event delegation via [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$('.parent').delegate('div', 'click', function(e) {
    // Here, `this` is the child div that was clicked
});

// or

$('.parent').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    // Here, `this` is the child div that was clicked
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/acoqax/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/acoqax/2/edit)

Note that the order of args is different between `delegate` (which I prefer for the clarity) and `on` (which it seems like everyone else prefers).

Comment: I prefer delegate over on aswell, but - "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method." Link: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ - So I would guess it depends on your Jquery version, and not preference, or am i wrong here? Just curious.

Comment: @Xeano: "Superceded" does not mean "deprecated." `delegate` has not been deprecated, not even in v1.9.2.

Comment: I tried to use `$(e.target).find('div')` to replace `$(e.target).closest('div')`, but not work, could someone please explain why?

Comment: @CharlesYeung: Look up [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) vs. [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest). They do completely different things (one looks for *descendants*, the other looks for the current element or *ancestors*). Since the `e.target` in a `click` event will almost always be the most deeply-nested element, `find` won't find anything, as `e.target` won't (usually) have any descendants.

Answer (score 3):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RNCu8/)**

You can look at the target of the event. Here the event is e.

```
$('.parent').bind('click', function(e) {
   console.log(e.target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.className` will get class name of div on which event fired.

```
$('.parent').bind('click', function(e) {
   if(e.target.className.indexOf('children') != -1) { // <-- Perform function only if any child is clicked
     // do something
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$('.parent').on('click', 'div', function() {
// ...
});
```

.on() should be used instead of .bind(). `this` references the clicked div in the event-handler.